# MySQL NOW() seems to correctly compare against a local datetime on my machine, but not on deployment

Tags: mysql, datetime, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

I have a SQL query with a where statement like this:

```
WHERE event.`local_time` > NOW()
```

in which `local_time` is a non-UTC datetime for the timezone in which the event's venue is. This seems to WORK PERFECTLY on my local build of the application, but in the deployment environment, we are getting a 5 hour offset from UTC (events are seen to happen five hours before they actually have).

What's going on here?

I've tried something like this:

```
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(event.`local_time`, venue.timezone, 'UTC') < NOW()
```

but that seems to return zero rows every time. (Note: our timezones are stored as 'America/New_York')

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, but especially any explanation of the discrepancy between my local machine and our deployment environment would be very helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are planning to use named timezones ("venue.timezone"). Make sure that "mysql.time_zone" table is populated in a same way on both ends.

To test if timezone info is loaded into MySQL:
select now(), CONVERT_TZ(now(), 'UTC', 'America/New_York');
If you get NULL in a second column - you do not have timezone loaded.

For Linux you can populate timezone related tables in mysql DB by doing:
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u U_S_E_R -p mysql

and test both sides again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that result from both places for the following query is the same:

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

If they are not, you can alway set global timezone with :

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = timezone;
or 
per connection with:
SET time_zone = timezone;
```

Check [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html) for the timezone topic (choose the appropriate MySQL version for your case).

Comment: I get SYSTEM, SYSTEM for both my local build and the live db